# Can't change data type in shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, csv, error-000210

I created a CSV with GEOID's and imported it into ArcGIS Pro. Arc is treating the GEOID's as numeric and the files as read-only. When I attempt to export the file to a geodatabase, converting the GEOID to text as part of the export, I get Error 000210. As a result I cannot join this file with a tract map where Arc has treated the GEOID as text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a `schema.ini` file to specify CSV column data type https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/adding-an-ascii-or-text-file-table.htm#GUID-3AF32EAC-2B43-4E33-BC5B-958FE4343D47

Answer (score 1):

I hacked an answer, creating a join on a secondary field, AFFGEOID. This field is the GEOID with the prefix "1400000US"; the "US" forces Arc to recognize all values as text. It's a little clumsier to work with than the GEOID field (9 characters longer), but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create dummy column GEOID2 and make it integer or preferable data type, and then calculate data from your GEOID. Also error 000210 is more about ArcGIS PRO locks or try saving different path.